# Am I hacked? Or what happened with my reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, association-bonus, hacked

I just logged in- and..

[image]

I am worried. Is it okay? Just to make sure, I don't use and never wished to use and never used a hacking engine.

Comment: You hit 200 reputation on [Boardgames.SE] on September 14th: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/27989/anatoly-wein?tab=reputation thereby qualifying for the association bonus.