# Has this tag been [hacked]?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

The tag [hacked](/questions/tagged/hacked) (18 questions) here on this site doesn't seem to have a clear use or intent.

The tag has a usage description, which states the following:

> Use for questions about hacked Stack Exchange accounts or about incidents in which Stack Exchange servers are, or may have been, hacked.

However, based on this definition, it seems the tag [security](/questions/tagged/security) (200 questions) would also cover such questions, and I don't see the need for this separate tag.

Looking through the questions using the [hacked](/questions/tagged/hacked) tag, most of them are indeed about security issues and the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag would be a good fit for them.

Should we remove this tag (and replace it with the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag where appropriate)?

Comment: Some of the questions aren't even about being "hacked" but just something unexpected that is not even malicious in origin. In [Am I hacked? Or what happened with my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333578) a user asks why they got a lot of rep when they merely qualified for association bonus and got it on all stacks they were a member of.

Answer (score 7):

I consider this a "sub tag" of [security](/questions/tagged/security). While indeed all hacking questions do belong to security, in general, the extra tag has a meaning and helps to identify and find the questions related to hacking.

I don't think it should be removed.

Comment: True, but this would make it a borderline meta tag. The general rule is that a tag should stand as the sole tag on a question (in addition to a required tag, of course).

Comment: @Sonic may be, but "borderline" isn't enough to justify nuking, IMO.